# How to add a comma to the end of every line in a json file

Tags: json, bash

The json file is too large for Notepad++ or vi to handle and causes "bad" characters to appear.

Before you close this and say it's duplicated, I saw an old thread and tried

```
sed 's/$/,/' filename
```

and it printed it to the screen but didn't save the commas in the file. I want to save as the same filename.

I tried adding `> filename` but it came out empty (used a test file so my big json file is safe).

I'm using Bash (Git bash) on a Windows XP machine and as far as I can tell the line endings are Unix style.

What is the problem?

ETA: Thanks, everyone, I added -i and it seemed to work great. The other solution using fold (?) did not work.

Comment: add `-i` parameter . `sed -i 's/$/,/' filename`

Comment: `sed` is a _stream_ editor, not a _file_ editor. So editing a file with `sed` is hopeless. What most people do is: redirect to a temporary file, e.g., `sed 's/$/,/' filename > tempfile` and then `mv tempfile filename`. With some versions of `sed`, there's the `-i` switch that does this behind the curtains.

Comment: `sed '...' file > file` doesn't work because before `sed` is ever started the shell has already opened (and truncated) the file for redirected output so `sed` (when it finally is run) only sees an empty file.

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate of another question asking how to append to the end of each line with sed. For the second question of why your approach didn't work, see [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/597244/why-does-redirecting-the-output-of-a-file-to-itself-produce-a-blank-file).